# Systems of equations in ConTeXt

Tags: equations, context, delimiters

In LaTeX+`amsmath`, I can say

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
  \left\{
    \begin{aligned}
      px-y-4&=0\\
      2x-2y-6m&=0
    \end{aligned}
  \right.
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

to get an aligned system of equations with a brace on the left.  How to achieve a similar effect in ConTeXt?  I tried saying `\startalign[left=\{]` and similar things with no effect.

**Edit:** thanks to Aditya's and Marco's comments below I came up with this:

```
\starttext
\startformula
  \startmathmatrix[left={\left\{},right={\right.},distance=0pt,align={right,left}]
    \NC px-y-4\NC{}=0\NC\NR
    \NC 2x-2y-6m\NC{}=0\NC\NR
  \stopmathmatrix
\stopformula
\stoptext
```

Now my question is: can this be made better?  I do not like the `distance=0pt` and `{}` stuff very much (but I guess this keeps the spacing on *both* sides of the equation sign uniform).

Comment: Use `mathmatrix`.

Comment: Could you show an example?

Comment: Here are two articles worth reading: [Using \startalign](http://dl.contextgarden.net/myway/mathalign.pdf) and [Display math in ConTeXt](http://dl.contextgarden.net/myway/context-latex-math.pdf)

Comment: I don't have an answer to the `{}` spacing issue. But to keep the code cleaner you can define your own environment: `\definemathmatrix[eqnsystem][left={\left\{},right={\right.},distance=0pt,align={right,left}]` and then use `\starteqnsystem … \stopeqnsystem` instead.

Comment: @Marco: could you make your comment into an answer, so that I could accept it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned in the documentation [Using
\startalign](http://dl.contextgarden.net/myway/mathalign.pdf) and [Display
math in ConTeXt](http://dl.contextgarden.net/myway/context-latex-math.pdf) you
can use the `\startmathmatrix … \stopmathmatrix` environment.

It makes sense to define your own environment for equation systems. This has
the advantage that it is logically marked up. *“This is an equation sytem”* as
opposed to *“This is a multi-line formula with a brace at the left”*. You can
change the layout of the equation systems globally and it keeps the source code clean and makes it easier to read.

I would also get rid of the ugly pair of braces. However, I don't have a
proper solution for the correct spacing (either wait for Aditya to tune in –
he's the expert for math or ask on the mailing list).

```
\definemathmatrix
  [eqnsystem]
  [left={\left\{},
   right=\right.,
   distance=.3em,
   align={right, left}]

\starttext
\startformula
  \starteqnsystem
    \NC px-y-4   \NC =0 \NC\NR
    \NC 2x-2y-6m \NC =0 \NC\NR
  \stopeqnsystem
\stopformula
\stoptext
```

[image: result]

Comment: Thanks a lot!  And what's wrong with the `.3em` approach?  It seems perfect!  (I'd also add a `\thinspace` after `\left\{`, but this is a matter of taste.)

Comment: The `.3em` seems arbitrary and a little hackish. I did some testing and found that the actual value is more about `.2278em`. I'd prefer the exact value that TeX uses for this distance.